# detectron2 - CUDA is not available

Tags: python, pytorch, detectron

I am trying out detectron2 and want to train the sample model.

When running the following code I get `(<class 'RuntimeError'>, RuntimeError('No CUDA GPUs are available'), <traceback object at 0x7f42b094ebc0>)`. Find below the code:

```
import detectron2
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
setup_logger()

# import some common libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

# import some common detectron2 utilities
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog, DatasetCatalog

from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
import random
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
import os


# To verify the data loading is correct, let's visualize the annotations of randomly selected samples in the training set:
register_coco_instances("fruits_nuts", {}, "../data/trainval.json", "../data/images")

fruits_nuts_metadata = MetadataCatalog.get("fruits_nuts")
dataset_dicts = DatasetCatalog.get("fruits_nuts")
'''
for d in random.sample(dataset_dicts, 3):
    img = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    visualizer = Visualizer(img[:, :, ::-1], metadata=fruits_nuts_metadata, scale=0.5)
    vis = visualizer.draw_dataset_dict(d)
    cv2.imshow('new', vis.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
    cv2.waitKey(0)
'''
# train model
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file("../detectron2_repo/configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("fruits_nuts",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()   # no metrics implemented for this dataset
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl"  # initialize from model zoo
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.02
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 300    # 300 iterations seems good enough, but you can certainly train longer
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 128   # faster, and good enough for this toy dataset
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 3  # 3 classes (data, fig, hazelnut)

os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

I ran the script `collect_env.py` from torch:

```
/home/project/.venv/bin/python /home/project/src/collect_env.py
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.10.2+cu102
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.2
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: glibc-2.31

Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)  [GCC 9.3.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-5.13.0-27-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243
GPU models and configuration: Could not collect
Nvidia driver version: Could not collect
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] mypy-extensions==0.4.3
[pip3] numpy==1.22.1
[pip3] torch==1.10.2
[pip3] torchvision==0.11.3
[conda] Could not collect

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am having on the system a RTX3080 graphic card. However, it seems to me that its not found.

Any suggestions why?

Is there a way to run the training without CUDA?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works for you. But let's see from a Windows user perspective.
I'm using Detectron2 on Windows 10 with RTX3060 Laptop GPU CUDA enabled.

The first thing you should check is the CUDA. You can check by using the command:

`nvcc -V`

It should be shown this message:

```
C:\Users\User>nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May__3_19:41:42_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0
```

And to check if your Pytorch is installed with CUDA enabled, use this command (reference from their [website](https://pytorch.org/)):

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

As on your system info shared in this question, **you haven't installed CUDA on your system**. And your system **doesn't detect any GPU (driver) available on your system**.
As far as I know, they recommended installing Pytorch [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) to run Detectron2 by (Nvidia) GPU.
(you can check on [Pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/) and [Detectron2 GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) for more details).

**Or, you can use this option:**

Add this line of code to your python program (as reference of this [issues#300](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/300)):

```
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cpu"
```

I hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: I would recommend you to install CUDA (enable your Nvidia to Ubuntu) for better performance (runtime) since I've tried to train the model using CPU (only) and it takes a longer time.